# How to add icons to tabbar items via the GUI designer

Tags: icons, ios6, tabbar

I have an iOS6 iPhone application, with a Tabbar and tabbar buttons. These buttons need icons and that's where the trouble starts. Added one icon to the project, double clicked on a button in the designer and associated the (questionmark) icon via the image combobox to the button. When I run the app on my iPhone, I do indeed see that the button now does indeed display a gradient-gray square, which turns into a gradient light-blue square, but the questionmark icon is not shown. The icon is a .png and the size is width 40, height 51. I changed nothing in the code.

Comment: Looks like somebody had the same problem here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1608127?threadID=1608127&tstart=0

Comment: From that link: "In other words, the actual colours of your image are ignored. The only interesting thing about each pixel, as far as UITabBarItem is concerned, is whether it's transparent or not.

The behaviour you are seeing is what will happen if you are using an image that is full of opaque pixels - in other words, what a normal, rational human being would think of as "an image".

How you make pixels transparent depends on the image editing program you are using."

Comment: So it looks like I need to make the pixels of my icon 'transparent', what ever that may mean. Does anybody know of a (large) set of public domain icons with 'transparent pixels'? Or alternatively, how I make them transparent myself?

Comment: That problem has been discussed here before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813096/are-there-free-iphone-navigation-bar-icon-sets-available

Comment: The official Apple documentation provides sample code, including icons: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html    Yet even these icons, like Icon-Small.png + Icon-Small@2x.png lead to the same result: default grey area + lightblue if selected.

Comment: Here I found demo code from Apple, which probably will help me: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tabster/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I solved my problem to the extent that I can work with it: you need so called 'transparent icons'. If I download these icons I can make them visible in my app and that is what counts; no idea how to produce these icons myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem to the extent that I can work with it: you need so called 'transparent icons'.